# How to query Azure Data Explorer database from Applications Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I want to have an integration from ADX to App Insights. I have only seen documentation about the other way around. Is there any way to query an ADX database from App Insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently you cannot query ADX from Application Insights. Please open the applicable item in [Application insights user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights)